# Strange crashes reported by Crashlytics on a Google "Mainline" device?

Tags: android, crash-reports

On almost every Play Store release of my app, I get weird crash reports of certain resource files being missing. Decompiling the APK shows the resources are there. The crashes are always by 1 user on 1 device.

The puzzling thing is the device model name is "Mainline" and the manufacturer is "Google". Looking around on Google, there is no device with the model name "Mainline" however there is a project named "Mainline". Does anyone know what is causing these crashes? Is Google running some weird test?

Screenshot from Crashlytics:
[image]

Comment: Seeing this too, not sure if this mean pixel line or something. Maybe its an issue with a pixel beta

Comment: I also just started seeing this show up in my Crashlytics all of the sudden today. Android 10 was released in 2019 and Mainline was an isolated component-based update system that was aimed at solving OS fragmentation from different manufacturers putting their own "flavor" on their devices. I'm guessing this is from one of the devices that takes advantage of that mainline OS update system and it shows in lieu of the device name.

Answer (score 2):

Google Mainline isn't an actual device. Mainline is a [Google project](https://www.androidpolice.com/project-mainline-android-14/).
[MTS](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/08/latest-artwork-on-hundreds-of-millions-of-devices.html) is a Google test environment based on the Mainline. The error could happen in the test process.
In my case, the `ERROR_MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE` error was related to the [lack of Google Play service](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID#public-static-final-string-error_missing_instanceid_service). This makes sense to me.